# What are some common HDFS commands that can be mapped in the bash files?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs, command-line-interface, putty

I am relatively new to Hadoop and I have been using HDFS CLI a lot. Commands like `hdfs dfs -ls` are becoming redundant to type. Is it possible to create an alias to this command (i.e., `h -ls`) in either the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files? Are there any other useful commands that I can map here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice is to put aliases in `.bash_aliases`.

For your problem, I'd put `alias h="hdfs dfs"` in my `.bash_aliases` file (create it if it doesn't exist)

Most distribs will already have this in their `.bashrc` file but if it's not there, add

```sh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

in your `.bashrc`

Now you can either type `source .bashrc` or restart you terminal and `h -ls` wille be interpreted as `hdfs dfs -ls`

Note that cou can also very well put all of your aliases directly in the `.bashrc`, but I find it more convenient to have all the aliases set appart.

> Are there any other useful commands that I can map here?

Look at this, it might give you some ideas : https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-aliases-mac-centos-linux-unix.html

And you can add what you want so if you run a command really often you can consider adding it in your aliases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I posted an update regarding the `.bashrc` differences. Can you provide some insight or do you prefer another question?

Comment: @JWeezy Sure, but I'm not sure i understand the question. Do you mean that the rest of the content of your bashrc is really different than the bit of code I provided?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to understand the difference in pattern that you suggested versus what is currently being used. I have posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58416260/4630376