# Trying to understand Bash file setups/structure

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs, command-line-interface, putty

This is an extension of a previously asked question: [What are some common HDFS commands that can be mapped in the bash files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58415032/4630376)

I notice that the .bashrc and .bash_profile that I was initially provided are slightly different that what you have provided. Is this OK or some kind of different pattern?

The files that were copied over when I started are as follows:

```
.bashrc
.bash_profile
```

**.bashrc**

```
source /etc/bashrc 

...and a lot of other folder mappings
```

**.bash_profile**

```
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
#if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
#       .    ~/.bashrc
#fi
source ~/.bashrc
```

I created the .bash-aliases file as you recommended.

**.bash_aliases**

```
alias h="hdfs dfs"
```

I have modified the `.bashrc` file as follows

**.bashrc** - Modified

```
source /etc/bashrc 

...and a lot of other folder mappings

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.bashrc` code will be executed each before a new shell is started. The code that is in there doesn't matter, as long as it is valid bash.

The other files (bash_aliases) are just here to separate the commands in different files.

This article explains it quite well: https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-bashrc.html

So to answer your question, it won't cause problems at all. All that matters is that the way it's done satisfies you.

Comment: So, can I rationalize things by moving all of the code in `.bashrc` into `.bash_profiles` and then compress the `.bashrc` to reference `.bash_profiles` and `.bash_aliases`?

Comment: @JWeezy bash_profile is a little bit different, it is used when bash is used as an interactive login shell (for instance when you `ssh`), so I wouldn't recommend doing that, unless you want your interactive login shell to have the same behavior than your "normal" shell. But yeah you can move your code from bashrc into a random file and then source that file frome bashrc

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I did not know that `.bash_profile` was **specifically** for interactive mode. Thank you for your help.